# LeafletJS Marker latitude and longitude is incorrect when placed within China

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

Today I had an issue with displaying leafletJS markers in the correct location. I got my latitude and longitude from Google Maps and created a marker with the same latitude longitude but it was maybe 30+ meters off. I'm working on something that requires high accuracy so this can't be happening. The two images I displayed here are the Google Maps marker, vs the leafletJS marker. Both have the same latitude and longitude.
[image]

[image]

Here is a Codepen of my problem: https://codepen.io/Rapidtransit22/pen/KKzymoG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>


    
</head>
<body>



<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([30.905554, 121.484461]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();





    

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks everyone. All I need is the marker to display in the correct location.

Comment: I would use [containerPointToLatLng](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-containerpointtolayerpoint) if you're not standing on the spot in real life. Code would be like `document.getElementById('mapId').onmouseover = function(e){ let b = this.getBoundingClientRect(), x = e.clientX-b.left, y = e.clientY-b.top, latLng = mymap.containerPointToLatLng(x, y), lat = latLng.lat, lng = latLng.lng; console.log('lat:'+lat+'; lng:'+lng) }`

Comment: China doesn't use GPS, they have their own positioning system called 北斗 that obfuscates GPS coordinates. So if you want accurate positioning in China, you need to use a Chinese api, more explanations on windover https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9Di-UVC-_4

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I'll take a look and let you know.